# Regex ambiguity

Tags: regex

Basic question about regex mechanics:

I have the following expression: `[10]*1[10]*`.

Would this match `100`?

My reasoning:
first option: `[10]*` matches "100" and then gets to the end of the string => no match.
second option: The `[10]*` is disregarded and the expression matches.

Am I forgetting something trivial, or will this actually depend on the regex engine?
(I remember something about greedy vs not greedy but I am not sure if that applies to this case)

Comment: Speaking of ambiguity. Is the `.` part of your regex or the end of your sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex engines do backtracking.

The engine tries to match `100` with `[10]*`, but that does not work, because then the `1` has nothing to match. But then the engine throws away the last character of the repetition (only using `[10]*` for `10`) and tries again. Still does not work, because `1` does not match `0`. The engine will throw away one character at a time, until the first `[10*]` is completely dropped. Now the `1` matches and `[10]*` gladly matches the rest.

I recommend reading through [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), because it explains **very** well what is going on under the hood. (For you particular problem, check out the section on Repetition).

Some more detail:

This does not depend on whether the repetition is greedy or ungreedy. The regex engine will always backtrack. It will just start from the other end (with 0 occurrences of `[10]`) if you make it ungreedy like this: `[10]*?`. In this case that would speed up the process, because the first try would already match, but it would not change the fact, that it always matches.

In fact, you can manually prevent the engine from backtracking, by making the repetition "possessive". If you do this, and the repetition is first left, then the engine will not try other possible repetitions. This would be the syntax: `[10]*+`. Now the engine would match `100` only with that first part. Then matching `1` would fail, but since you made the repetition possessive, it would not go back to try different options to use `[10]*`. In this case that is useless, of course, but there are use cases where this behavior is desirable. And all of this is also covered in the linked tutorial. ;)

Comment: "The regex engine is eager to return a match". Interesting, I wonder how slow a regex would get if you introduced several cases like this one after the other.

Comment: lol, I'm going to go crash some Regex testing sites now :). Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, yes it matches, because the regex parser will consume as much from each sub-expression as it needs to achieve a match on the whole expression.

In your case, to match it will do this:

- the first `[10]*` will consume zero chars
- then it will match the literal `1`
- then the last `[10]*` will consume the remaining input

Finally, instead of asking here, why not try it out on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) and see for yourself!

Comment: That is a bit simplified, don't you think? ;)

Comment: @m.buettner actually no, because this is a very simple question. my first sentence captures everything needed to explain it imho

Comment: at the same time it declares the OP's assumption partly wrong, that the engine tries to match `100` with `[10]*` which it does in fact. From the question I rather assumed, that the OP wanted to know what the engine actually does, and not just what the meaning of the repetition is. But I might as well have overestimated that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is easy enough to test. Here is a little php script:

```
<?php
if (preg_match('/[10]*1[10]*/', '100')) {
    echo "It matches.\n";
} else {
    echo "It doesn't match.\n";
}
?>
```

And the output is:

```
It matches.
```

An explanation: After some trial and backtracking of the regex engine, the net result is that the first `[10]*` doesn't match. The `1` matches the text `1` and the second `[10]*` matches the text `00`.

Comment: Sure, I ran it through regextester.com first, but I wasn't sure if this is true in general.